# How to set colors in PSReadLine in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

[PSReadLine](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine) in PowerShell has syntax coloring, but how do you specify the colors?

Comment: Does anyone know why the default colors are so unreadable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple different ways.  You can do this:

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Comment -ForegroundColor Green
```

Alternatively:

```
$options = Get-PSReadlineOption
$options.CommentForegroundColor = Green
```

The possible colors are from the .NET [ConsoleColor Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The actual RGB color values can be changed in the console properties dialog.

To see the current color settings, execute `Get-PSReadlineOption` by itself.

Comment: Great. Thanks. Do you know if there's any way to specify numeric RGB colors?

Comment: Not with PSReadline.  There are only 16 possible colors available in the console.  The RGB values are stored in the registry and typically changed in the Properties dialog of the console.  ConsoleColor (a .Net enum) is really just an index into one of those 16 possible colors - so the name doesn't matter - if you change the right entry, it will just read the registry for that slot.

Comment: Hello, I can't find a way to set those colors in my profile file. It seems `Get-PSReadlineOption` is not defined and return nothing when executed from the profile file. Once the shell is loaded, there's no problem however. I tried adding an implicit `Import-Module PSReadline` before those lines but nothing do.

Comment: @JasonShirk The colors are set for the current instance of powershell. If I close and start it again the changes disappear. How can I make the changes stick?

Comment: @krv - Add the settings to your profile.

Answer (score 7):

While the methods that Jason Shirk describes still work on my Mac that has PowerShell Core version 6.0.1, as documented [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PSReadline/Set-PSReadlineOption?view=powershell-5.1), they no longer work on my Linux machine, which is on version 6.1.0.

It seems that they completely changed the interface of this cmdlet: [PowerShell 6 Set-PSReadlineOption](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-6).

Now, you can supply a hash table of colors as the value to the `-Colors` parameter. The good thing is that you now have many more color options.

From the examples:

```
$colors = @{
  # ConsoleColor enum has all the old colors
  "Error" = [ConsoleColor]::DarkRed

  # A mustardy 24 bit color escape sequence
  "String" = "$([char]0x1b)[38;5;100m"

  # A light slate blue RGB value
  "Command" = "#8470FF"
}

Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors $colors
```

Comment: And how do you specifiy the missing color. I don't know whether foreground or background is missing but one color is not enough.

Comment: @LeeMeador, could you be more specific about your issue? What is a missing color? Are you able to run my example? FWIW, I am able to run it in PowerShell 7.1.1