# Set PSReadLine colors and then persist them

Tags: powershell

For some reason powershell is displaying operators and parameters as invisible.
Using this question I can fix this: [How to set colors in PSReadLine in PowerShell](https://superuser.com/questions/676140/how-to-set-colors-in-psreadline-in-powershell)

```
$colors = @{Operator="Green";Parameter="Green"}
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors $colors
```

This is good, but then if I close Powershell and bring it up again it has reverted back to the original settings.

A comment on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/676587/63076) says "Add the settings to your profile".

How do I do this? How do I add these settings to my profile?